# How can i make a graph as shown in image?

Tags: java, swing, graph, jfreechart

[image]
Currently when i run this code it shows me a graph as shown above, i want to draw a graph that i've shown. Currently its drawing a graph symmetric about the (0,0), I think making it drawn from (0,-3) or (0, < -2) should do the work. Is there any other way for doing this?

Current Code:

```
public class Profile  {



    double last=0;
    ChartFrame frame1;
    JToolBar jt=new JToolBar();
    public void generateProfile(int[] pointValue,double[] distance){
        ArrayList pv=new ArrayList();
        ArrayList dist=new ArrayList();

        pv.add(pointValue);
        dist.add(distance);
        int min=pointValue[0];
        for(int i=0;i<pv.size();i++){
            //System.out.print(pointValue[i]);
            if(pointValue[i]<min){
                min=pointValue[i];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<dist.size();i++){
            System.out.print(distance[i]);
        }


        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Average Weight");
        for(int i=0;i<pointValue.length;i++){
            //if(pointValue[i]!=0){
              series.add(last,pointValue[i]);
              last=distance[i];
            //}
         }


      XYDataset xyDataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
      JFreeChart chart= ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart("Profile View Of Contour", "Distance", "Contour Value", xyDataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
      ValueAxis rangeAxis = chart.getXYPlot().getRangeAxis();
      rangeAxis.setLowerBound(-3);
      frame1=new ChartFrame("XYLine Chart",chart);

      JButton saveimg=new JButton(new AbstractAction("Save as Image"){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //some other lines of code...
            }
      });
      jt.add(saveimg);
      frame1.add(jt, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      frame1.setVisible(true);
      frame1.setSize(300,300);
    }



    public static void main(String ar[]){
        Profile pro=new Profile();
        int[] pv={2,3,0,5,-2,10};
        double[] dist={1,4,8,12,14,20};
        pro.generateProfile(pv, dist);



    }
}
```

Comment: You may be able to adapt one of the approaches shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8866390/230513).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for this in the `XYAreaRenderer`. However it shouldn't be too hard to implement this. Have a look at the code of the `XYAreaRenderer.drawItem()` method. Within this method there is a local variable `transZero` that is calculated using the actual zero value (0.0). If you just replace 0.0 by some other value this will probably do what you need.

The easiest way to achieve this is to create your own renderer that derives from XYAreaRenderer and overrides `drawItem()`. In this method copy the original code and modify it as described above.

You then just need to use this new renderer by writing

```java
XYAreaRenderer yourNewRenderer = ...; /* initialize here */
chart.getXYPlot().setRender(yourNewRenderer);
```